# Make an <img> element appear on hover and remain on click that corresponds with the same ID of button being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have explored many ways of making an image appear upon clicking an element, such as display: block or visibility: visible or .show(). However the issue I am having is to have an image appear inside a different div container whose  class matches the button id the user is hovering and clicking on. Also  another issue making the image remain after click. Any advice would be great.

HTML

```
<div id="list">
  <div id="button-list">
    <ul>
        <li id="header1" class ="inactive"><h2>Upper Body</h2></li>
        <li id="front-neck" class="upper">Front Neck</li>
        <li id="back-neck" class= "upper">Back Neck</li>
        <li id="trapezius" class= "upper">Trapezius</li>
        <li id="shoulder" class= "upper">Shoulder</li>
        <li id="biceps" class= "upper">Bicep</li>
        <li id="triceps" class= "upper">Tricep</li>
        <li id="forearm" class= "upper">Forearm Extensor</li>
        <li id="forearm" class= "upper">Forearm Flexor</li>
        <li id="header2" class="inactive"><h2>Lower Body</h2></li>
        <li id="hamstring" class="lower">Hamstring</li>
        <li id="calf" class="lower">Calf</li>
        <li id="it-band" class="lower">IT Band</li>
        <li id="adductor" class="lower">Adductor</li>
        <li id="quadricep" class="lower">Quadricep</li>
    </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
    <div id="anatomy-container">
        <img class="front-neck" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/front-neck2.png"/></span>
        <img class="back-neck" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Back-Neck-2.png"/></span>
        <img class="trapezius" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Traps2.png"/></span>
        <img class="shoulder" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Interior-Deltoid2.png"/></span>
        <img class="biceps" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Bicep-2.png"/></span>
        <img class="triceps" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Tricep2.png"/></span>
        <img class="forearm" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/extensor2.png"/></span>
        <img class="forearm"src ="http:// m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/FLEXER2.png"/></span>
        <img class="hamstring" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Hammy2.png"/></span>
        <img class="calf"src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Calf2.png"/></span>
        <img class="it-band" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IT-BAND-2.png"/></span>
        <img class="adductor" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Addcutor2.png"/></span>
        <img class="quadricep" src ="http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Quad2.png"/></span>
    </div>
<div id="list-container">
  <ul id="container">
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 body {
  padding-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monaco, monospace;

}
h1 {
  font-size: 30px
}
h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none; 
}
#header1, #header2 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#header1:hover, #header2:hover, #header1:active, #header2:active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.upper, .lower {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.upper:hover, .lower:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
}
#list {
    position: relative;
}
#button-list{
    width: 300px; 
}
#highlight{
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}
#list-container{
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding:10px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
}
#front-neck{
 left: 300px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 400px;
}
#tasdf{
  height:85px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var jsonString = {
  "stretches": [{
    "area": "front-neck",
    "name": "front-neck",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/fneck1.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "back-neck",
    "name": "back-neck",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IMG_1173.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "side-neck",
    "name": "side-neck",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/sideNeck.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "entire-neck",
    "name": "neck-rolls",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/neckRollStretch.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "trapezius",
    "name": "upper-trapezius",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/trapStretch3.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "trapezius",
    "name": "lower-trapezius",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/trapStretch.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "trapezius",
    "name": "trapezius",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/trapStretch2.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "shoulder",
    "name": "shoulder-raise",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/shoulderRaise.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "shoulder",
    "name": "shoudler",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IMG_1198.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "shoulder",
    "name": "arm-circles",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/shoulderCircles.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "shoulder",
    "name": "elbow-circles",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/elbowCircles.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "shoulder",
    "name": "upward-shoulder",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/upwardShoulder.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "triceps",
    "name": "tricep",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/tricepStretch.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "triceps",
    "name": "tricep-side",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/tricepSideStretch.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "biceps",
    "name": "standing-bicep",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/bicepStanding.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "biceps",
    "name": "seated-bicep",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/bicepSeated.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "biceps",
    "name": "bicep-side",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/bicepSide.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "forearm",
    "name": "forearm-bench",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/forearmTable.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "forearm",
    "name": "standing-forearm",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/forearmWall.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "forearm",
    "name": "wrist-circles",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/wristCircles.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "it-band",
    "name": "seated-glute",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/seatedGlute.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "it-band",
    "name": "ankle-to-knee",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ankleToKneeGlute.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "it-band",
    "name": "across-body",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/acrossBody.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "it-band",
    "name": "leg-swings",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/legSwings.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "hamstring",
    "name": "leg-swings",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/legSwingsHam.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "hamstring",
    "name": "hamstring",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/hamstring.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "hamstring",
    "name": "walking-kicks",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/hamstringWalking.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "hamstring",
    "name": "lying-hamstring",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IMG_1217.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "hamstring",
    "name": "leg-up-hamstring",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/legUpHamstring.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "calf",
    "name": "ankle-circles",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ankleCircles.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "calf",
    "name": "calf-wall",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/wallCalf.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "calf",
    "name": "seated-calf",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/seatedCalf.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "calf",
    "name": "stair-calf",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stairCalf.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "adductor",
    "name": "butterly",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/butterflyAdductor.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "adductor",
    "name": "standing-groin",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/standingAdductor.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "adductor",
    "name": "leg-swings",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/legSwings.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "adductor",
    "name": "sumo",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/sumoAdductor.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "quadricep",
    "name": "kneeling-quadricep",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/kneelingQuad-1.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "quadricep",
    "name": "lying-quadricep",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lyingQuad.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "quadricep",
    "name": "bench-quadricep",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/benchQuad.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }, {
    "area": "quadricep",
    "name": "scorpion",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/scorpionQuad.jpg",
    "type": "dynamic"
  }, {
    "area": "quadricep",
    "name": "sitting-quadricep",
    "pic": "http://m68.siteground.biz/~stretc22/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/sittingQuadricep.jpg",
    "type": "static"
  }]
}

$(function() {
 //THIS IS WHERE I INSERTED THE FUNCTION
  $("#anatomy-container img").hide();
  $('li').on("click,hover", "#button-list li", function() {
    imgClass = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#anatomy-container img").hide(); // hide all images
    $("#anatomy-container ." + imgClass).show(); //show only image that  
  });

  $("li.upper").hide();
  $("li.lower").hide();
  $("#header1").on('click', function() {
    $("li.upper").slideToggle();
    var buttonState = $("li#header1").attr("class");
    if (buttonState == "inactive") {
      $("li#header1").removeClass("inactive");
      $("li#header1").addClass("active");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "#4CAF50",
        "color": "white"
      });
    } else {
      $("li#header1").removeClass("active");
      $("li#header1").addClass("inactive");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "white",
        "color": "black"
      });
    }
  });
  $("#header2").click(function() {
    $("li.lower").slideToggle();
    var buttonState = $("li#header2").attr("class");
    if (buttonState == "inactive") {
      $("li#header2").removeClass("inactive");
      $("li#header2").addClass("active");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "#4CAF50",
        "color": "white"
      });
    } else {
      $("li#header2").removeClass("active");
      $("li#header2").addClass("inactive");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "white",
        "color": "black"
      });
    }
  });
  $("li.upper").on("click", function() {
    var buttonState = $(this).attr("class");
    if (buttonState == "upper inactive") {
      $(this).removeClass("upper inactive");
      $(this).addClass("upper active");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "#008CBA",
        "color": "white"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("upper active");
      $(this).addClass("upper inactive");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "white",
        "color": "black"
      });
    }
  });
  $("li.lower").on("click", function() {
    var buttonState = $(this).attr("class");
    if (buttonState == "lower inactive") {
      $(this).removeClass("lower inactive");
      $(this).addClass("lower active");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "#008CBA",
        "color": "white"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("lower active");
      $(this).addClass("lower inactive");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "white",
        "color": "black"
      });
    }
  });
  //THIS IS THE AREA I'M TRYING TO FIX!!!

  var myData = jsonString;
  var newContent = '';
  var selected = null;
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selected = $(this).attr("id");
    newContent = "";

    /** Perhaps a quite different json structure could remove the for loop **/
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.stretches.length; i++) {
      if (selected == myData.stretches[i].area) {
        newContent += '<li id = "' + selected + '-img" class = "' + myData.stretches[i].area + '">';
        newContent += '<a href="' + myData.stretches[i].ref + '">'; /** ref is not defined in JSON **/
        newContent += '<img src="' + myData.stretches[i].pic + '">';
        //newContent += '<p "'+responseObject.stretches[i].name+'">';
        newContent += '</a> + </li>';
      }
    }
    console.log(newContent);
    $('#container').html(newContent);
  });
});
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle that reproduce the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RyeGuy/0m5xjmdm/

Comment: sorry I dont understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Ok I changed the html and used css to display the functionality I would like. I would use this but I need two separate <div> containers for functionality down the road, but I do not know how to make it work using two <div> elements. https://jsfiddle.net/RyeGuy/0uf479s5/

Comment: you want to reproduce the hover effect using jquery instead of css?

Comment: Yes and do so with two separate div elements. (see html in first jsfiddle link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with jQuery. As you describe in the question you have a list of buttons and image corresponding to that button.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#button-list li", function() {

        imgClass = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#anatomy-container img").hide(); // hide all images
        $("#anatomy-container ." + imgClass).show(); //show only image that class match with button id 

    });
    $(document).on("mouseover", "#button-list li", function() {

        imgClass = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#anatomy-container img").hide(); // hide all images
        $("#anatomy-container ." + imgClass).show(); //show only image that class match with button id 

    });
});
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I like this solution. However when I insert into my code it does not function properly. Any suggestions? (Edited above)

Comment: Write separate event handler for click and mouseover and it will work fine. I have change my answer take a look.